# Weinberg's spontaneous broken symmetries

Tags: path-integral, symmetry-breaking, 1pi-effective-action

Steven Weinberg in his second volume of QFT's book (in section about spontaneously broken symmetries, in subsection about Goldstone bosons) writes following:

if we have linear transformation of fields 
$$
\tag 1 \varphi^{m} \to \varphi^{m} + i\varepsilon \sum_n t^{mn}\varphi_{n},
$$
under which classical action and path integral measure is invariant, then quantum effective action $\Gamma [\varphi ]$ is also invariant under $(1)$. Then he says that let's consider only case when theory is translational-invariant and fields are constant in space-time. The next calculations are based on this assumption.

But did he discuss only this case? Many results about Goldstone bosons which are obtained in case of constant fields be generalized in an arbitrary case? If no, why Weinberg assumes only this case?

Edit. It seems that the answer is following. We consider the vacuum state of the theory, i.e., stationary point of corresponding action. Since theory is translation invariant, stationary point doesn't depend on coordinates.

Comment: For the record: Weinberg QFT Vol. 2 p. 167 eq. (19.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

He considers this case, because for this case, the effective action $\Gamma[\phi] = -\mathcal{V}_3TV(\phi)$, such that the $<H>_{\Omega}/\mathcal{V}_3 = V(\phi)$. Basically so that he could use the results of section 16.3.